# adding property to neo4j using csv and cypher

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher

Hello I want to create and set the property date on the already set nodes for that I have a csv with columns with ids (tdrdrug_id) and with dates (decimnaldate). The csv gets read perfectly but cypher cut when using the query

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///drug_dates" 
AS line 
MATCH (n:DRUG {drug_id : line.tdrdrug_id })
SET n.date = line.decimnaldate
```

I get as a result 
(no changes, no records)

Thank you for reading any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If drug_id on your :DRUG nodes is numeric, you'll need to cast your id from the CSV to integer:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000 LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///drug_dates" AS line 
MATCH (n:DRUG {drug_id : toInt(line.tdrdrug_id) }) 
SET n.date = line.decimnaldate
```